# Cannot get SharedArrayBuffer to work in android webview, although it works in both chrome and firefox on both android and desktops

Tags: javascript, android, webview, sharedarraybuffer

I am trying to run mupdf built as web assembly in a webview on Android.

I have set the response headers correctly as far as I know, and this is illustrated by the fact that the web page using the web assembly works fine on desktop browsers and android browsers (including Chrome which uses a version of webview).

But when running a program of my own which uses a webview, the page when loaded gives a console message saying SharedArrayBuffer is not defined.

What I expect is that the webview in my program, when loading, should work the same as in the browsers.   All other pages I use, with complex javascript, work the same way.   But this one reaches the attempt to create a SharedArrayBuffer, and fails with an error in the console.

When I go to the page that tries to load the web assembly code, and which uses a Shared ArrayBuffer, I have checked and in every browser,

window.isSecureContext is true and
window.crossOriginIsolated is true

however, in the webview in my program

window.isSecureContext is true BUT window.crossOriginIsolated is false

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same issue and there doesn't seem to be anything about this on the internet.

Webview (109.0.5414.117) doesn't seem to support cross-origin isolation, and my Xiaomi Redmi 7a Android 10 can't update to the newest version as of this writing (110.0.5481.64).

This is quite bad because there are a lot of phones that don't support newer versions of Webview and never will.

Here is the only discussion regarding this topic that I managed find: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6182

[On some platforms, Site Isolation is not available, due to implementation or resource constraints.](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/process_model_and_site_isolation.md#modes-and-availability)

Comment: If you are still concerned about this, comment back.   I can't fit much in a comment.   But I submitted bug report to Android and they told me yes webview does not support this, but they don't show where this is document, NOR EXPLAIN how other browsers that allegedly USE WEBVIEW do support this.  Somehow those other browsers are allowed to to isolation using webview.  Just an everyday person cannot do it in their own code??

Comment: I see that site isolation is not yet supported on WebView, on my phone I have v120.0.6099.43